# update a value by running through every row in a data frame with conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, if-statement

I have a starting balance of 'Points = 500', and as I run through this data frame, the point value will update as it goes through every row. Here is the data frame:

| Index | A | B | A_yes | B_yes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.43 | 1.55 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2.58 | 1.49 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1.61 | 2.32 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2.7 | 1.46 | 1 | 0 |

What I'm trying to do is update 'Points' based on the following conditions for every row:

For example, row 1:

If A_yes = 1 then multiply the current 'Points' value by the first row in the 'A' column (2.43). (Otherwise if it was B_yes that equalled 1, then the 'Points' value would have been multiplied by the first row in the 'B' column (1.55)).

So Points = 500 * 2.43 = 1215

Second row:

Now that Points = 1215, this will be used for the next row and the same process will be followed,
If A_yes = 1 then multiply 'Points' by the value in the A column (2.58), however because A_yes = 0, then if B_yes = 1 then multiply 'Points' by the 'B' column (1.49) and updated 'Points' now = 1810.35

I'm new to pandas and not sure how to create a function that will run through all the rows and update the 'Points' value in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiple columns `A,B` by `Yes` columns, then multiple first row by `500`, then `sum` both columns and add cumulative product by [`Series.cumprod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html):

```
cols = ['A','B']

df1 = df[['A','B']].mul(df[['A_yes','B_yes']].to_numpy())
df1.loc[0, cols] *= 500

df['Point'] = df1.sum(axis=1).cumprod()
print (df)
      A     B  A_yes  B_yes       Point
0  2.43  1.55      1      0  1215.00000
1  2.58  1.49      0      1  1810.35000
2  1.61  2.32      1      0  2914.66350
3  2.70  1.46      1      0  7869.59145
```

Comment: thanks! and if i wanted to halve the points value before continuing onto the next row everytime, can i still use series.cumprod? where would i modify the code to do this?

Comment: @monica - Do you think divide `2` before `cumprod`? `df['Point'] = df1.sum(axis=1).div(2).cumprod()` ?

Comment: yess that works like a treat, thanku so much :D

Comment: accepted :)  i have one more slightly complicated scenario with how to use cumprod, how would i accumulate it in this way? say: i have the 500 at the start, halve it into two 250's. I take one of the 250's and multiply this by the row to get 607.5 but then before proceeding onto the next row, i add the other half (250) so now i have 857.5. then i continue this pattern through all the rows. is it possible to do something like this before the .cumprod()? thanks again

Comment: @monica - Can you create new question with expected ouput?

Comment: Just created the new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662788/update-a-value-by-running-through-every-row-in-a-data-frame-with-conditions-ext