# update a value by running through every row in a data frame with conditions (extension)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

This is an extension to the question, 'update a value by running through every row in a data frame with conditions' [update a value by running through every row in a data frame with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74652350/update-a-value-by-running-through-every-row-in-a-data-frame-with-conditions)

Working with the same data frame:

Df:

| Index | A | B | A_yes | B_yes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.43 | 1.55 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2.58 | 1.49 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1.61 | 2.32 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2.7 | 1.46 | 1 | 0 |

I've attached an image of the new conditions.

(For example, for the first row: I have the 500 at the start, halve it into two 250's. I take one of the 250's and multiply this by the row to get 607.5 but then before proceeding onto the next row, I add the other half (250) so now I have 857.5. Then I continue this pattern through all the rows.)

[image]

Desired output:

Df:

| Index | A | B | A_yes | B_yes | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.43 | 1.55 | 1 | 0 | 875.5 |
| 1 | 2.58 | 1.49 | 0 | 1 | 1067.5875 |
| 2 | 1.61 | 2.32 | 1 | 0 | 1393.2017 |
| 3 | 2.7 | 1.46 | 1 | 0 | 2557.42324 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following with `df` your dataframe:

```py
start = 500
weights = (df["A"].where(df["A_yes"].eq(1), df["B"]) * 0.5 + 0.5).cumprod()
df["Points"] = start * weights
```

- Use [`.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas.Series.where) to select between the value in `A` or `B` based on the `A_yes` and `B_yes` entries (my assumption here is that there's a 1 either in `A_yes` or `B_yes`, but not in both).
- Calculate the average between the selected value and 1.
- Build the actual `weights` with [`.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html#pandas.Series.cumprod).
- Multiply the `weights` with the `start` value to get the `Points`.

Result for `df =`

```
      A     B  A_yes  B_yes
0  2.43  1.55      1      0
1  2.58  1.49      0      1
2  1.61  2.32      1      0
3  2.70  1.46      1      0
```

is

```
      A     B  A_yes  B_yes       Points
0  2.43  1.55      1      0   857.500000
1  2.58  1.49      0      1  1067.587500
2  1.61  2.32      1      0  1393.201688
3  2.70  1.46      1      0  2577.423122
```

Comment: thanks! I have another extension to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74701440/update-a-value-by-running-through-every-row-in-a-data-frame-with-conditions-ano, would you know how to resolve this?