# update a value by running through every row in a data frame with conditions (another version of extension)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, conditional-statements

This is a further extension of my previous question [update a value by running through every row in a data frame with conditions (extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662788/update-a-value-by-running-through-every-row-in-a-data-frame-with-conditions-ext)

Working with the same data frame that has an added column:

Df:

| Index | A | B | A_yes | B_yes | Win/Lose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.43 | 1.55 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2.58 | 1.49 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1.61 | 2.32 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 2.7 | 1.46 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Where in the Win/Lose column 1 = win and 0 = lose.

Currently I have this code to generate the following output:

```
start = 500
weights = (df["A"].where(df["A_yes"].eq(1), df["B"]) * 0.5 + 0.5).cumprod()
df["Points"] = start * weights
```

Output Df:

| Index | A | B | A_yes | B_yes | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.43 | 1.55 | 1 | 0 | 875.5 |
| 1 | 2.58 | 1.49 | 0 | 1 | 1067.5875 |
| 2 | 1.61 | 2.32 | 1 | 0 | 1393.2017 |
| 3 | 2.7 | 1.46 | 1 | 0 | 2557.42324 |

How can I modify it so that it follows this pattern that now depend on the win/lose column:

[image]

Desired new output:

| Index | A | B | A_yes | B_yes | Win/Lose | Points |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.43 | 1.55 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 857.5 |
| 1 | 2.58 | 1.49 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 428.75 |
| 2 | 1.61 | 2.32 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 707.4375 |
| 3 | 2.7 | 1.46 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1308.75912 |

Comment: Hi, how do you get `707.4375`?